# Can I transfer content from an existing iPhone to a new iPhone which is using a new (different) Apple ID?

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id

I am trying to cut myself off from the family shared AppleID. I've just bought myself a new Macbook and have set up a new Apple ID. I have also just got a iPhone 5 to replace my dying 4.

My question is, can I back up the contents of my iPhone 4 and then bring that content onto the iPhone 5 with the new apple ID. I understand that I'll lose the apps that would need to be purchased again, I guess I'm more concerned about the contacts, notes, and photos.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little hesitant to post this because I can't try it right now and there is, as always, a chance that it won't work. But, because you are willing to repurchase apps, the transfer should be fairly achievable.

I would first restore from a backup of your old iPhone to your new iPhone. If you have already setup the new iPhone then you would need to wipe it and start over which would erase any data that you have created since getting the new phone. Through this process, you will sign in with your old Apple ID. After everything is restored, I would delete the iCloud account off your phone. It should ask you whether you want to keep notes, contacts, calendar, etc. choose to keep all of those items. Sign into your new Apple ID and create a backup of your data.

Again, as I'm sure you are aware, you will still have to work through your apps and repurchase or download all of them again. Apps like Evernote are easy because your data is in your account and you would just have to sign back in. Other apps like games are notorious for losing data.

Comment: I think that this should work.

Comment: Keep in mind when signing out of the old appleid and into the new one that there are multiple places to do that, as mentioned iCloud, but also Itunes and app store, messages, facetime, game center and possibly email.  Then again, maybe you want to leave some of those signed into the old... like messages and facetime for example.

Answer (score 0):

For contacts, you can [export contact information as a vCard](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH3606?locale=en_US) and then [import a vCard](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH3605?locale=en_US).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any good way of doing so. What comes to mind is you could restore the backup of the old phone and sync data with apps on the computer so that it has all the contacts and such locally. Then wipe the new phone, set it up with your new Apple ID and no backup, then sync it with the same computer. I think then it'll put all that old information on your new phone, which will put it in the new ID's iCloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

Just restore your new iPhone from a backup of your old one, then sign it out from the old Apple ID (you need to do this in several places in the settings app, AppStore, find iPhone, iCloud....)

Sign it in to your new Apple ID. You shouldn't have any problem with contacts, mailboxes etc. the only thing you'll probably lose is all of the application sandboxes, but if you turn on family sharing before you do it hopefully you won't even lose those